# Приостановка и действие в другом потоке по нажатию кнопки

Tags: c#, многопоточность

У меня есть цикл который работает в отдельном потоке и другой цикл нем выполняет действия, мне нужно по нажатию кнопки из стартового потока остановить второй цикл и сделать действия, которые должен был сделать другой цикл.

Как это реализовать?

**Main()**:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(Autoriz);
        thread1.Start();

        void Autoriz()
        {
           Otcev();
        }
```

Вторичный метод:

```
 int count = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PatchAplicationDataTempOriginal).Length;
        List<long> id = DataApi.paramsID();
        Print("Начата отсев > до : "+ (idFace.Count-1));

        for (int i9 = 0; i9 < id.Count-1; i9++)/// первый цикл 
        {
           CountOut= Sravnenie(id[i9], CountOut);
        }
        int count1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PatchAplicationDataTemp).Length;
        Print("Закончен отсев > результат : "+ count1);
```

Сравнение:

```
Stopwatch sWatch3 = new Stopwatch();

        int count= (Directory.GetFiles(PatchAplicationDataTempOriginal).Length);
        for (int i5 = 0; i5 < count; i5++)
        {
            sWatch3.Start();
            try
            {


                bool a = ImageVerification( PatchAplicationDataTempOriginal + "\\" + i5 + ".jpg", PatchAplicationDataTempFace + "\\" + Face_prov + ".jpg");
                if (a)
                {
                  // действие
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) { Print("Ошибка отсева > "+e.ToString() );break; }
            sWatch3.Stop();
            t++;
        }
```

Кнопка должна дублировать метод `ImageVerification()` и при нажатии одной из двух кнопок (`true`/`false`) выдавать значение в `а`.

Comment: Например, обернуть действия в потоке в метод и просто из потока вызывать метод. Потом в другом потоке убить первый поток(если это возможно, я не помню). Потом вызвать из потока метод, который выполнял убитый поток.

Comment: P.S. И приведите пример кода

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: Чёт я не понял вот это: "...и сделать действия, которые должен был сделать другой цикл.". Какой другой цикл? Один цикл вложен в другой, это понятно. Останавливаем внутренний цикл, а дальше то, что?

Comment: записываем значение в `a` заместо метода `ImageVerification` или сразу выполнить  действия которые в `if` (неважно что за действие)